# Асинхронное подключение JS файлов, а также выполение функций которые в них находятся!

Tags: include, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте! Разрабатываю что-то подобное FormAPI друпала. В друпале есть реализация подгрузки нужных скриптов а также выполнение определенных функций при создании AJAX форм. В друпал это все прекрасно функционирует, но мне пришлось отказаться от него из-за большой нагрузки и прожорливости!

Реализовано это так:

Добавляем нужный JS файл:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/script.js');
```

И пишем какие команды выполнить после отправки AJAX формы:

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'call_login_form', array($form_id));
/* Отправляем js команды */
return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

Я уже переписал практически все нужное что мне нравилось из FormAPI друпала, и AJAX формы в том числе! Но при реализации вызова подобных инвоков появились следующие загвоздки: Файлы при подключении повторяются, если AJAX форма отправляются несколько раз. А также если инвок вызывает функцию которая находиться в подключаемом файле, то после первой отправки формы, требуемые JS файлы еще не успевают подгрузиться.

Пробовал использовать JS библиотеки для управления инклудами JS файлов, такие как **yepnopejs** (http://yepnopejs.com/) и **Bootstrap** (https://bitbucket.org/scott_koon/bootstrap), но толку никакого!

Обе библиотеки умеют исключать дублирование инклудов.

Убибилиотеки **yepnopejs** есть такие функции как **callback** и **complete**, которые выполняют нужные действия после подгрузки, но так как у меня форма может отправятся несколько раз, то выполнение действий происходит только один раз, также как и подключение инклудов(а нужно каждый раз при отправки формы)!

Если у кого-то есть какие нибудь соображения по этому поводу, или кто-то решал подобную задачу, поделитесь пожалуйста опытом! Заранее благодарен!

Comment: ничего не понял, вам нужно грузить js по запросу ? require.js не подойдет ? 

или вам нужно просто выполнять команды после ajax запроса ? 

при чем тут js если вы приводите код php ?

Comment: У меня есть php функция, которая обрабатывает принятую AJAX форму, и возвращает результат в JSON. После, когда JS принял JSON, обработал его и вывел html результат в нужный регион (wrapper). Пример использования - Кнопка "+1". То есть при нажатии на кнопку, отправляеться форма, php скрипт ее обрабатывает, заносит +1 в БД, генерирует новую форму с новым значением (в нашем случае колличетсвом нажатий на нопку) и возвращает форму JS скрипту. JS скрипт заменяет старую форму (кнопку) на новую. А также после этого всего вызываеться дополнительная JS функция к примеру с сообщением "спасибо!".

Comment: Данный метод реализован очень хорошо в друпале в FormAPI, поэтому если вы сталкивались с Друпал, поймето о чем идет реч!

Comment: "или вам нужно просто выполнять команды после ajax запроса ?" - да именно! Но только если они есть в ответе на AJAX запорс от PHP скрипта. А также нужно подключать перед их выполнением JS файлы, также если они упомянуты в ответе!

"и в чем проблема ? передавайте параметром вашей функции ajax js функцию." - я и передаю, с этим проблем нет. Но также мне нужно подключить еще JS файлы, в которых есть требуемые функции. А они у меня подключаються после выполнения! Нужно наоборот! Подключить сразу все - не вариант! Мне нужно передавать всегда разные функции и разные файлы для подключения!

Comment: вот с примером jquery как обрабатывать множественные callback, 
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bmVw5/

написать нужный вам функционал не сложно.

Comment: почему восклицательные знаки ? в общем вы разберитесь с форматом ответа, и всё будет нормально, скрипты можно грузить например так:

function load_scripts(scripts) {
 var script=scripts.shift();
 if (typeof(script)==='function') {
  script();
  return;
 }
  if (script.type=="js") {
   var s=document.createElement('script');
   s.onload=function() {load_scripts(scripts);}
   s.src=script.src;
   document.head.appendChild(s);
   return;
  }  
  var l=document.createElement('link');
  l.rel="stylesheet";
  l.href=script.href;
  document.head.appendChild(l);
  load_scripts(scripts)
 
}

Comment: параметры для функции выше выглядят так например:

    scripts=[{type: "css",href: "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"},
    {type: "js",src: "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"}
   ],function() {alert(this)}]

Comment: Это все очень хорошо! Только такой вопрос: если я несколько раз буду подключать один и тотже скрипт (в случае с повторными оправками формы) скрипты будут заново подгружатся? (Если да, это не хорошо и не правильно). И вопрос №2: функции не начнут выполняться раньше чем подгрузятся скрипты?

Примерно также и делал... Попробую еще раз! Огромное спасибо за Ваши советы!

Answer (score 1):

Спустя 1 год, отвечаю на свой вопрос: спасаясь от прожорливости Drupal, достаточно было перейти на фреймворк Yii :)